# How decode base64 image PIL

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I've some trouble with decode base64 image in my django project.

I am passing the image to views like this (I've some form. I'm passing image to function from views.py through this form):

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="content" class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center p-0">
    <div class="row bg-white shadow-sm">
       <div class="col border rounded p-4">
        <h3 class="text-center mb-4">Диагноз</h3>
        <form action="" id="post-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p align="center" style="font-weight:bold"><label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Снимок</label></p>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image-selector">
            </div>
        </form>
        <p align="center" style="font-weight:bold">Predictions</p>
                <p>Covid: <span id="covid-prediction"></span></p>
                <p>Health: <span id="health-prediction"></span></p>
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img id="selected-image" class="img-thumbnail" width="300px" height="300px" src=""/>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>
                            <button id="predict-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Predict</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    let base64Image;
    $("#image-selector").change(function() {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            let dataURL = reader.result;
            $("#selected-image").attr("src", dataURL);
            base64Image = dataURL.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");
            console.log(base64Image);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL($("#image-selector")[0].files[0]);
        $("#covid-prediction").text("");
        $("#health-prediction").text("");
    });
    $("#predict-button").click(function(event){
            let message = base64Image;
            console.log(message);
            $.post("{% url "diagnose:submit_prediction" %}", message, function(response){
                $("#covid-prediction").text(response.prediction.covid.toFixed(3) * 100 + "%");
                $("#health-prediction").text(response.prediction.health.toFixed(3) * 100 + "%");
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
</script>
```

And in my views file I'm trying to decode this image like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def predict_chances(request):
    myDict = request.POST.dict()
    encoded = 0
    for k in myDict:
        encoded = k

    print(encoded)
    
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(encoded)))
    
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(224, 224))
    prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()

    response = {
        'prediction': {
            'covid': prediction[0][0],
            'health': prediction[0][1]
        }
    }
    
    return jsonify(response)
```

But this is not working. I get this error:

> binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

How I can fix this?

Comment: That error means that you're trying to decode something that isn't actually Base64 data.  It looks like you're trying to decode a *key* from your dict - surely the data would be a value from the dict, instead?

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variable. It seems you should use `myDict[encoded]` instead of `encoded`. But if you use form to send image file then you don't have to decode it but use directly `io.BytesIO(myDict[encoded])`

Comment: btw: `button` should be inside `<form> </form>` to send it. If you put outside form then it will not send it and you would need JavaScript to send it. And you need `enctype="multipart/form-data` to send file data - if you don't use it then it sends only filename without file data.

Comment: I tried to print "encoded" and I get next: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4SCWRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABgALAAI..." . It seems to be base64 coded image. For this picture I've error  "binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (68229) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4". for other I've error from this question

Comment: you use very strange method to get data from `request.POST.dict()` - it may get different element instead of `file`. You should add `name="image` in `<input ...>` and later use `POST["image"]` to make sure you get file. Or maybe you should even use `request.FILES["image"]` isntead of `request.POST`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: in encoded file usually there is space between `data:image/jpeg;base64,` and `data` - like `data:image/jpeg;base64,<space>data` - and maybe you didn't remove this space and you have wrong data. You could also check `len(encoded)` to see if it has correct lenght. You could also display it in `JavaScript` to compare if you send and recv the same data.